# Redirecionamento com click jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento

Tenho uma página Home na qual ao clicar em um item do menu, redirecione a outra página e de um `click` em determinado serviço em um menu "acordeao/sanfona".

Tenho algo parecido com isso:

```
var index = $(this).parent().attr('index');
        $(window.document.location).attr('href', 'index.php/servicos');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.'+ index +' img').click()
        }, 1000);
```

Não fazer ficar bonitinho aqui rs.

Mas isso não está funcionando. Dei um `alert()` e pelo que me parece ele da o comando dentro do `setTimeout` ANTES de ir para a outra página.

Comment: Sim, faz sentido ele ser executado antes de ir para outra página (Que eu saiba, é impossível executar um código em uma página, redirecionar para outra e o código afetar a página seguinte, posso estar errado). O ideal é você repassar a informação de qual item foi clicado para a próxima página.

Repassando por ser por cookie, GET, POST, Session Storage, Local Storage ou na própria lógica via servidor/cliente na página em questão.

Comment: Você está a usar uma iFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma não é possível, pois não tem como você executar o objeto de outra página através da página atual por javascript.

O que eu aconselharia seria você passar na URL

```
var index = $(this).parent().attr('index');
$(window.document.location).attr('href', 'index.php/servicos/'+index);
```

E na página de serviços no caso, verificar se chegou esse get, e se caso tenha chegado, execute: `$('.'+ (o get que passou) +' img').click()`

Comment: Ainda assim não funciona.

Teria quer ser algo como `'index.php/servicos?index=' + index);`

Comment: Achei que estava usando htaccess, qual linguagem de programação está usando?